# Is SignalR suitable for getting result of a server side (background) processing?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC web page in which the user uploads a file, in server side the file is processed, then some results must be displayed in the very same page.

I've picked ajax upload (so no page reload done upon [Upload] button) which works fine. The controller's action method with the file called, all OK. I am using an upload component, it seems the "success:" callback is not available for me to react.

*** EDIT** 
Besides of the success callback seems not available, the processing takes 60 sec. I would like to return to the upload ajax call **immediately**, then process (optionally show progress on the client), and when the processing is complete show the result.
 **END EDIT ***

My first KISS (an amateur) thought was: OK, then store the processing result in server side in session, and ajax poll from the client an action method what returns with the result. Btw it is not so KISS.

My second thought was: OK, then go to professional, and use SignalR. (I've never used). Now I am going though on the chat tutorial, and I have doubts: Is not SignalR overkill for this simple task? and also: Is SignalR suitable for this task at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using SignalR for something somewhat similar: Generating and sending out a newsletter to 10+k recipients. This whole process takes about 5 minutes and the admin can follow the progress via SignalR.

SignalR looks complicated initially but it really isn't. One of the advantages I'd say is the ease of use. During your processing it is really simple to push updates to the client. Making it work in the client only needs a handful of javascript lines.

The overkill part here I guess is that you'll always only broadcast to 1 person.

Comment: Yes, exactly the broadcast capability was the point where I got doubts (not the complexity), so I thought first ask.

Comment: well, the library really takes care of that part, so you don't have to worry about that one bit.

Comment: Also, it might be a good exercise. You might want to use SignalR in the future for something bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Signal R can give the response to the specific client on success.. but yes its overkill. why don't you send a response(string or object) from server side after checking whether the data was successfully posted.This reduces the overkill of implementing signal R

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let's suppose the processing takes 60 sec. I would like to return to the upload ajax call immediately, then process (optionally show progress on the client), and when the processing is complete show the result. (I am going to edit question)

Comment: In that case AJAX is most suited.Signal R could be handy for real time status.